# Does IsolatedStorage File.Append mode has an error with the the '\n'?

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

When appending a file using IsolatedStorage API and adding a \n at the end of the string the file is empty and if adding it in the beginning of the string it erases the file then adds the requested data only

```
    IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                string fileContents = "\n"+str+ " " + txtblock1.Text;
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContents);
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Th.txt", FileMode.Append, file))
                {
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    stream.Close();
                }
```

So what should I do in that case to add a new line then write in the file ?

Comment: Can you show how you read the file?

Answer (score 2):

I've not come across that issue but try using `Environment.NewLine` instead

```
string fileContents = Environment.NewLine + str + " " + txtblock1.Text;
```

or `\r\n`.

```
string fileContents = "\r\n" + str + " " + txtblock1.Text;
```

Generally, `Environment.NewLine` is fine but there may be certain scenarios where you want more control over the characters in which case you can use `\r\n` to add a new line.

Edit based on comment. `Environment.NewLine` is working fine in `Append` mode.

```
string fileContents = Environment.NewLine + "test";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContents);

using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Th.txt", FileMode.Append, file))
    { 
         stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    using (var read = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Th.txt", FileMode.Open, file))
    {
         var stream = new StreamReader(read, Encoding.UTF8);
         string full = stream.ReadToEnd();
         Debug.WriteLine(full);
    }

}
```

Comment: well when using any of those cases the whole file is deleted and the new value only gets written

Comment: I just tried it and it's working fine for me. `Environment.NewLine` doesn't affect the `Append` aspect. Since you're already setting `Append` there's no need for you to manipulate the stream's position manually. Seems to me you're doing something wrong elsewhere (possibly reading it wrong incorrectly).